# python decorator is object

Tags: python, wrapper, decorator

```
dict_proxy({.....'showMe4': 'function wrapper1 at 0x0C1BD150', 
            'showMe3': 'classmethod object at 0x0C1BF630'.....
```

Why is it if I define my own decorator using a wrapper (e.g. `wrapper1`) for my function (e.g. `showMe4`) in some class (e.g. `myClass`) it is listed in `myClass.__dict__` as a function but the Python decorators such as `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` (and I assume all Python defined decorators?) if applied to my function (e.g. apply `@classmethod` to `showMe3`) get listed as objects?

Answer (score 0):

Decorators can be functions or classes (implementing `__call__`). In the latter case the decorated function is actually an instance of class used to decorate the function.